# Codeigniter displaying of set_message not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a problem with regards to displaying my error message coming from the set_message on the form_validation. Please see some part of my code below.

These are some parts my view:

```
 <div class="uk-margin">
     <?php if (form_error('name')){ ?>
          <span class="reg_error"><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
     <?php } ?>

     <div class="uk-form-controls">
          <input class="uk-input" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my controller:

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Full Name', 'trim|callback_alpha_space');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->load->view('register');
    }else{
         ....
    }
```

and also I have a function under controller:

```
 function alpha_space($str){
    if (!$str){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_space', 'The {field} field is required.');
        return FALSE;
    }else if (!preg_match("/^([-a-z_ ])+$/i",$str)){
        $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_space', 'The {field} field can not contain number or special characters.');
        return FALSE;
    }else{
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

What happening is that, rules are working but somehow message are not being displayed. Appreciate your help on this. Thanks!

Comment: How sure are you that the rule is working? i.e. how do you determine that they do? I'd bet that the rule itself isn't called (and that also means it will fail).

Comment: Cause if the rule did not work it should be redirected to other pages, but what happens is that the rule works because it redirects to the same page (in which it should be displaying supposedly the error message)

Comment: I don't see a redirect in the code shown, but regardless of that - if the rule is *declared, but not called*, that would result in a validation failure - leaving you on the error page, but with no error to display. That doesn't mean the rule worked, it means there was a failure.

Answer (score 0):

In your alpha_space function, check your preg_match function. Add the "/" character to the end of the REGEX, like this: `'/^([-a-z_ ])+$/i/'`

Comment: You can also say echo form_error('name', '<span class="reg_error">', '</span>') so that you don't need to check if(form_error('name'))